# Reverse lookup of git config

Tags: git

How can I reverse lookup a config key given a value?
My config contains

```
[url "https://someurl/"]
    insteadOf = https://somealias/
```

Specifying the value `https://somealias/`, I want to retrieve`https://someurl/`.

Could make a workaround with `git config --get-regexp`, but that's not maintainable. More near misses:

- Only in a working dir

  ```
  git remote get-url https://somealias/
  ```
- Returns much more than the desired URL

  ```
  git remote show -n https://somealias/
  ```

Comment: Do you need to achieve this directly via `git config`, or can you parse the underlying config file directly?

Comment: Yes I could parse the config file. But so does `git` and I was hoping to lean on that.
This should work under Windows and Linux, so not sure if there is a ini-parser available.

Comment: Quick and dirty would be to search `git config --list`.

Answer (score 0):

It is (why oh why ls-remote)

```
 git ls-remote --get-url https://somealias/
```

> --get-url
> Expand the URL of the given remote repository taking into account any "url..insteadOf" config setting and exit without talking to the remote.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the translations, `--get-regexp` is your friend. For casual use:

```
git config --get-regexp url somealias
```

and I have

```
$ git gr alias.gr
alias.grl !f() { git config --local --get-regexp "${@-.}"; }; f
alias.gr !f() { git config --get-regexp "${@-.}"; }; f
```

so in my own use I'd

```
git gr url somealias
```

and refine the patterns to avoid any punning if I cared, e.g. `^url` to get only the aliases instead of all remotes using the pattern and any odd matches, or `'^url\.|\.url$'` or whatever.